# Python - script doesn't execute the rest of code after is daemonized

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have this code:

```
import os
import time

def createDaemon():
    try:
        pid = os.fork()

        if pid > 0:
            print ('PID: %d' % pid)
            os._exit(0)

    except OSError as error:
        print ('Unable to fork. Error: %d (%s)' % (error.errno, error.strerror))
        os._exit(1)

    doTask()

def doTask():
    file = open('/tmp/tarefa.log', 'w')

    while True:
        file.flush()
        time.sleep(2)

    file.close()

def myfunction():
    # do something, I am not implementing the code, it's useless for the question

createDaemon()
myfunction() # it is never executed.
```

As you see in the comment, I want to execute myfunction() but it doesn't. What can I do? I am not writing the content of myfunction() because it's useless for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never reaches the call to `myfunction()` because of this:

```
while True: # <----- 
    file.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The infinite loop causes the thread to sleep for 2 seconds indefinitely. Remove the loop, and it works.

Comment: Causes the thread to sleep _for_ 2 seconds rather than ever (or every if that's what you meant)?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, typo. Thank you!

Comment: @AllExJ Sorry. You'll have to open a new question. If this answer helped, accept it, close it, and open a new one. Constantly changing a question reduces its usability for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

So, lets think about this. After the fork you have 2 processes, one of which you close right after. The other process then goes into doTask which has an infinite loop, it will just sleep for 2 seconds indefinitely. That is why no process actually goes further than your createDaemon() call.